# Android sensor listeners not responding with fragments added and removed from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, wear-os

I have an Android handheld app and an Android wear app that both use fragments and listen for shaking gestures using the sensor manager and custom listeners that I have made.

On each app I have a main fragment that contains a menu and a sensor manager with my custom listeners registered. When a user selects a menu item, the main fragment is replaced with the menu item fragment (the menu item fragment has it's own sensor manager with different custom listeners), and when you go back from the menu item fragment, popBackStackImmediate() is called to return to the main fragment.

This works perfectly on the handheld app, and on the wear app it works fine too, for a while; if you open the menu item fragment and then go back to the main fragment continuously, after 5 or 6 times doing this the sensor listeners become sluggish, and eventually stop working. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

This is how I handle registering and unregistering the listeners with the sensorManager in each of the fragments:

**Main Fragment**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private MainWearActivity mMainWearActivity;
    View view;

    private SensorManager mSensorMgr;
    private ShakeListener shakeListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMainWearActivity = (MainWearActivity) getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mSensorMgr = (SensorManager) mMainWearActivity.getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        shakeListener = new ShakeListener();

        shakeListener.setOnShakeListener(new OnShakeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShake() {
                    MenuItemFragment mif = new MenuItemFragment();
                    mMainWearActivity.replaceFragment(mif, "menuFrag");
                }
            }
        });

        startListening();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        stopListening();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        stopListening();
        super.onDestroyView();
    }


    private void startListening(){
        mSensorMgr.registerListener(shakeListener, mSensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    private void stopListening(){
        mSensorMgr.unregisterListener(shakeListener);
    }
}
```

**Menu Item Fragment**

```
public class MenuItemFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;
    private MainWearActivity mMainWearActivity;
    private SensorManager mSensorMgr;
    private FragmentManager fManager;
    private ShakeListener shakeListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMainWearActivity = (MainWearActivity) getActivity();
        fManager = getFragmentManager();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_item, container, false);

        mSensorMgr = (SensorManager) mMainWearActivity.getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        shakeListener = new ShakeListener();

        shakeListener.setOnShakeListener(new OnShakeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShake() {
                fManager.popBackStackImmediate();
            }
        });

        startListening();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        stopListening();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        stopListening();
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    private void startListening(){
        mSensorMgr.registerListener(shakeListener, mSensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    private void stopListening(){
        mSensorMgr.unregisterListener(shakeListener);
    }
}
```

**Method to Replace Fragment**

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment frag, String fragTag) {
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag, fragTag);
    mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Like I say, this set up works fine on the handheld app, but on the watch the sensor listener malfunctions after loading and going back from the menu item fragment. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**

So as per the suggestions, I have moved my fragments to the MainActivity class so that they can be re-used. I have also changed the replaceFragment method to this instead:

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment frag, String fragTag) {
    Fragment currentFrag = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .remove(currentFrag)
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag, fragTag)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

I have placed Logs in the onResume() and onPause() methods of the MainFragment and the MenuItemFragments to check whether they are being called and can confirm that they are.

I have also moved the SensorManager to the MainActivity and use that to register/unregister listeners, which themselves have been moved to the OnCreate() method of each fragment so that new listeners are not being created every time the view is created.

After all this the same problem persists. I can go into a MenuItemFragment and back to the MainFragment maybe 8-10 times before the listeners/sensors stop working. I have also looked at the memory tab of AndroidMonitor in Android Studio as I am going into and out of the fragments, and it appears to fill up steadily until the allocated amount reaches about 5MB before the sensors crash.

Answer (score 0):

My testing indicates that `onResume()` and `onPause()` don't get called by `FragmentTransaction.replace()`, so it wouldn't surprise me if they also don't get called when that transaction is popped off the back stack. You can confirm this in your own code by adding some logging to your `onResume()` and `onPause()` methods and watching when they get called.

If this is indeed the case, the workaround I've used is to call `FragmentTransaction.remove()` and `add()` instead of `replace()`. So your `replaceFragment` method body would then look like this:

```
Fragment currentFrag = fragMgr.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .remove(currentFrag)
    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag, fragTag)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. I was thinking perhaps that the problem I was having might be to do with creating new sensor managers and listeners in onCreateView and creating a new fragment every time I want to open the menu item. Does it matter that a new fragment is created every time? Or would it eventually fill up my memory, which could be causing the sluggish behaviour?

Comment: I tried that out, but I'm still getting the same problem with the sensors crashing after replacing the fragments a number of times.

Comment: You ought to be reusing fragments when you can, but I wouldn't expect that simply creating a new listener in `onCreateView` would cause the problem. But it'd be worth moving some of those local vars into fields and keeping them around for future use rather that recreating them. Are your `onPause` and `onResume` methods getting called? What's the crash you're getting (ie, logcat)?

Comment: Can you place some logging around when you create and remove sensorlisteners? It looks like you might be starting a new one each time you launch a menu item fragment and each time you start a main fragment. The watch hardware might not be able to keep up.

Comment: You mean when I'm registering/unregistering the listeners? Or when I'm instantiating them?

Comment: @String So I tried moving the sensorListeners into fields and instantiating them in onCreate() so that they are re-used every time. I also moved the fragments into my MainActivity and re-use them, along with the fragment manager. I checked that the onPause() and onResume() methods are called when the fragments are loaded/replaced and they are being called. Still though, the same problem persists.

Comment: Well, there's no reason to re-instantiate them if their containing fragment still exists - that's why I suggested "moving some of those local vars into fields". But generally, adding more logging is an excellent way to gain insight into this kind of issue. I'd put it at all of the important points (instantiating, un/registering, etc) for now, and see what that tells you.

Comment: Again - what's the crash you're getting? Can you copy the relevant logcat rows into your OP?

Comment: @String there is no crash log, the sensors or listeners just stop working. I can still navigate the app manually, just not using gestures.

Comment: Reading your latest comments... There's clearly a memory/resource leak occurring, and it's possible that it's in the framework, not your code. You could try creating a minimal test case; if the same problem persists, report it at http://b.android.com - and if not, then work from there to your live code to isolate the issue. But also, if this only happens after 8-10 iterations of opening/closing the menu - that's kind of an edge case. Given that touch navigation does still work, you could could mark it as a "known issue" in your app and move on.